# Shortest path from one source which goes through N edges

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, shortest-path

In my economics research I am currently dealing with a specific shortest path problem:

Given a directed deterministic dynamic graph with weights on the edges, I need to find the shortest path from one source S, which goes through N edges. The graph can have cycles, the edge weights could be negative, and the path is allowed to go through a vertex or edge more than once.

Is there an efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: is there any destination node ?

Comment: Can you clarify "goes through N edges", do you mean exactly N edges? (or at least N edges)

Comment: There is no destination nodes, the only constraint on the paths are that they go through exactly N edges.

Comment: To illustrate the idea : all vertices are a "state" of the economy. And two vertices are linked by an edge if there exists a "decision" which allows the economy to jump from one state to an other at every time step. Therefore, you can stay on the same state (the same vertex) by "doing nothing" as a decision. Each decision has a "cost" that evolves in time which is modeled by dynamic weights on the edges. And I am looking to the paths through which the economy can go after N decisions (therefore N time steps as there is one decision per time step) and therefore N edges.

Comment: If cycles are allowed, can the same edge be used again and again?

Comment: yes ! but only a maximum number of N times.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93620/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51099146/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be:

First find the lowest edge-weight in the graph.

And then build a priority queue of all paths from the starting edge (initially an empty path from starting point) where all yet-to-be-handled edges are counted as having the lowest weight.

Main loop:

1. Remove path with lowest weight from the queue.
2. If path has N edges you are done
3. Otherwise add all possible one-edge extensions of that path to priority queue

However, that simple algorithm has a flaw - you might re-visit a vertex multiple times as i:th edge (visiting as 2nd and 4th is ok, but 4th in two different paths is the issue), which is inefficient.

The algorithm can be improved by skipping them in the 3rd step above, since the priority queue guarantees that the first partial path to the vertex had the lowest weight-sum to that vertex, and the rest of the path does not depend on how you reached the vertex (since edges and vertices can be duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

The "exactly `N` edges" constraint makes this problem much easier to solve than if that constraint didn't exist. Essentially you can solve N = 0 (just the start node), use that to solve N = 1 (all the neighbors of the start node), then N = 2 (neighbors of the solution to N = 1, taking the lowest cost path for nodes that are are connected to multiple nodes), etc.

In pseudocode (using `{field: val}` to mean "a record with a field named `field` with value `val`"):

```
# returns a map from node to cost, where each key represents 
# a node reachable from start_node in exactly n steps, and the
# associated value is the total cost of the cheapest path to 
# that node
cheapest_path(n, start_node):
  i = 0
  horizon = new map()
  horizon[start_node] = {cost: 0, path: []}
  while i <= n:
    next_horizon = new map()
    for node, entry in key_value_pairs(horizon):
      for neighbor in neighbors(node):
        this_neighbor_cost = entry.cost + edge_weight(node, neighbor, i)
        this_neighbor_path = entry.path + [neighbor]
        if next_horizon[neighbor] does not exist or this_neighbor_cost < next_horizon[neighbor].cost:
          next_horizon[neighbor] = {cost: this_neighbor_cost, path: this_neighbor_path}
    i = i + 1
    horizon = next_horizon
  return horizon
```

We take account of dynamic weights using `edge_weight(node, neighbor, i)`, meaning "the cost of going from `node` to `neighbor` at time step `i`.

This is a degenerate version of a single-source shortest-path algorithm like Dijkstra's Algorithm, but it's much simpler because we know we must walk exactly N steps so we don't need to worry about getting stuck in negative-weight cycles, or longer paths with cheaper weights, or anything like that.

Comment: I am not sure this would fit. The weights have their own dynamics, meaning that after going through the first edge, the weights on all the edges can vary. Therefore I don't think a successive analysis of the neighbors like so would work.

Comment: I missed that constraint, though I'm not sure whether it makes a difference. Does that variation depend on the particular path already taken, or is it just a function of what what step number we're on? I.e., is the cost function `cost(from_node, to_node, i)`, or `cost(from_node, to_node, path)`? If the latter, do we know anything about the way that function behaves?

Comment: The dynamics of the weights is given as an entry of the algorithm and is independant from the paths or the nodes.

Comment: In that case I don't see why the algorithm as given (imagining that `edge_weight` takes into account dynamic edge costs, so call it `edge_weight(node, neighbor, i)`) wouldn't work. What are you seeing that I'm not?

Comment: with N = 2
Be an oriented graph ABC and A the source and : 
at time t = 1 
weight(AA;t=1) = 2
weight(BB;t=1) = 2
weight(CC;t=1) = 2
weight(AB;t=1) = 1, weight(BC;t=1) = 3 and weight(CA;t=1)=4 

at time t = 2 
weight(AA;t=2) = -2
weight(BB;t=2) = 5
weight(CC;t=2) = -2
weight(AB;t=2) = 1, weight(BC;t=2) = 1 and weight(CA;t=2)=4 

The answer in my case is : 
A-A-A as the length of this path is weight(AA;t=1)+weight(AA;t=2) = 2 - 2 = 0

If I understood correctly, the answer of your algorithm would be
A-B-C but weight(AB;t=1)+weight(BC;t=2) = 1 + 1 = 2 > 0

Comment: No, my algorithm gives that A has a cost of 0. We're keeping and working on the costs of reaching _every_ node at each step, not just the cheapest node. So  horizon 0 is `{A:0}` (just the starting point), horizon 1 is `{A:2, B:1, C:4}` (cheapest cost to reach each node using T1 weights starting with horizon 0 starting points), and horizon 2 is `{A:0, B:3, C:2}` (cheapest extensions using T2 weights using horizon 1).

Comment: Does the method is able to give also the final path and not only the final horizon ? Thank a lot for all of this ! And I am not sure on how you took into account the dynamics of the edges ?

Comment: Updated my answer to add paths and be explicit about dynamic edge weights.

Comment: You said it is a "degenerate version of a single-source shortest-path algorithm like Dijkstra's Algorithm" - however in my problem there are possible edges with negative weights. Would this work as well or should I use a Bellman-Ford like algorithm rather than a Dijkstra's inspired algorithm ? Thanks a lot.